# CocoaPods update yields Error loading the plugin `slather-2.4.9`

Tags: cocoapods

Does anyone know why I might be getting a slather error when using the latest CocoaPods on a Mac?

pod update

```
---------------------------------------------
Error loading the plugin `slather-2.4.9`.

Gem::ConflictError - Unable to activate slather-2.4.9, because activesupport-5.2.6 conflicts with activesupport (>= 4.0.2, < 5)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2302:in `raise_if_conflicts'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1418:in `activate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:93:in `safe_activate_and_require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:31:in `block in load_plugins'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:30:in `map'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:30:in `load_plugins'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:326:in `block in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
----------------------------------
```

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same issue: ``` Error loading the plugin ``slather-2.4.9``. ```, but with another project.

This worked for me:

```
sudo gem update slather
```

Comment: for me: `sudo gem install slather -n /usr/local/bin`